# Selecting lines to delete with an implicit join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete

I have two tables with a many-to-one relation. I can select items in the "child" table with a criteria in the parent table using an implicit join:

```
select * from child,parent where child.parentid=parent.id and parent.name like 'foobar%'
```

Is there a better (more efficient, more elegant) way to delete children that a plain:

```
delete from child where child.parentid in (select id from parent where parent.name like 'foobar%')
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server) hints that I could do:

```
delete child from child,parent where child.parentid=parent.id and parent.name like 'foobar%'
```

But on PostgreSql (through SquirrelSQL) I get a syntax error... of course I have long table names so the actual request is more like:

```
delete c from child c, parent p where c.parentid=p.id and p.name like 'foobar%'
```

So is this supported by PG, or is there another way?

Bonus points: can I delete items from the two tables using:

```
delete from child,parent where child.parentid in (select id from parent where parent.name like 'foobar%')
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) DELETE requires a `USING` when you want to join tables. Your linked answer is for SQL Server, not for Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete from both tables in one statement using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with deleted_parent as (
  delete from parent
  where name like 'foobar%'
  returning id
)
delete from child
where id in (select id from deleted_parent)
```

Comment: Thx. Also figured out the USING syntax for the single-table deletion. Will accept answer as soon as SO lets me...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging the powers of your database by creating a foreign key with the `on delete` cascade option:

```
alter table child
    add constraint child_parent_fk 
    foreign key (parentid) references parent(id)
    on delete cascade;
```

On top of enforcing data integrity across tables, this will manage the deletion in the child table when a parent is removed, so you can just do...

```
delete from parent where name like 'foobar%'
```

... and rest assured that children will be deleted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres, syntax for what you are trying to do is using "USING"

```
delete from child C USING parent P where C.parentid=P.id 
and P.name like 'foobar%'
```