# How do I delete rows in one table where the ID matches another table row where a field is a certain value?

Tags: sql-server

I admit the title question is convoluted; here is the situation.

I have two tables:

```
USERS Table
```

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monica | A |
| 2 | Ross | A |
| 3 | Phoebe | T |
| 4 | Chandler | A |
| 5 | Rachel | T |
| 6 | Joey | A |

```
PERMISSIONS Table
```

| user_id | permission_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 1 | 51 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 22 |
| 2 | 18 |

What I want is a way to delete all rows from the `PERMISSIONS` table where that user's `STATUS` is "T" but how would I do that?

I had tried this:

```
DELETE FROM permissions
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM users
    WHERE status = 'T'
);
```

However, SQL Server gives this error: `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: check out this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

Comment: This form of subquery could work, although a join is easier. But the issue with this query is that `user_id` is not a column in `users`. If you alias the tables you will see what I mean `SELECT u.user_id FROM users u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try apply  `join` `permissions`  and  `user` and `where status = 'T'`

Example:

```
DELETE p
FROM permissions p
INNER JOIN users u
  ON p.user_id=u.id
WHERE u.status = 'T'
```