# delete all results of a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to delete all results selected by this select statement, how do I do that?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    db.wp_term_taxonomy A,
    db.wp_terms B
WHERE
    A.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND B.term_id = A.term_id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: You can achieve "deleting the rows" by deleting from either table, so there's no join, or from both tables. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_term_taxonomy;
 CREATE TABLE wp_term_taxonomy(term_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, taxonomy VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_terms;
 CREATE TABLE wp_terms(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, term_id INT NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy VALUES (1,'post_box'),(2,'post_bag');
 INSERT INTO wp_terms VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2);

 DELETE a,b FROM wp_term_taxonomy a JOIN wp_terms b ON b.term_id = a.term_id WHERE a.taxonomy = 'post_bag';

 SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy;
 +---------+----------+
 | term_id | taxonomy |
 +---------+----------+
 |       1 | post_box |
 +---------+----------+

 SELECT * FROM wp_terms;
 +----+---------+
 | id | term_id |
 +----+---------+
 |  1 |       1 |
 |  2 |       1 |
 +----+---------+
```

As an alternative, see the CASCADE options of InnoDB tables

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. `DELETE a,b FROM db.wp_term_taxonomy a JOIN db.wp_terms b ON b.term_id = a.term_id WHERE a.taxonomy = 'post_tag';`

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE B.* FROM db.wp_terms B
INNER JOIN db.wp_term_taxonomy A  ON B.term_id = A.term_id
WHERE (A.taxonomy = 'post_tag');


DELETE FROM db.wp_term_taxonomy
WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
FROM
db.wp_term_taxonomy A,
db.wp_terms B
WHERE
A.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND B.term_id = A.term_id
```

Comment: I didn't know you could delete across tables like this.

Comment: Can't delete entries like this.

Comment: @Rao why do you think so? do you want to delete the records from both tables?

Comment: @tftd Yes, I want to delete only the rows and NOT the table from both tables, ie., all the rows returned by above `SELECT` statement