# Is it possible to delete from multiple tables in the same SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row, cascading-deletes

It's possible to delete using join statements to qualify the set to be deleted, such as the following:

```
DELETE J
FROM Users U
inner join LinkingTable J on U.id = J.U_id
inner join Groups G on J.G_id = G.id

WHERE G.Name = 'Whatever'
and U.Name not in ('Exclude list')
```

However I'm interested in deleting both sides of the join criteria -- both the `LinkingTable` record and the User record on which it depends. I can't turn cascades on because my solution is Entity Framework code first and the bidirectional relationships make for multiple cascade paths.

Ideally, I'd like something like:

```
DELETE J, U
FROM Users U
inner join LinkingTable J on U.id = J.U_id
...
```

Syntactically this doesn't work out, but I'm curious if something like this is possible?

Comment: No, a DML statement can affect only one table. Your option is to remove one of the constraints (and potentially enforce it using a trigger instead).

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer in your question that you have foreign keys pointing in both directions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks--that was the answer I was looking for: DML statements can affect only one table, and thus what I want is impossible. We'll have to figure out another way around this. If you write an answer to that effect I'll mark it.

Comment: @ bwerks As the  Delete statement affect only one table you can use `"deleted" pseudo table` to delete the values from more than one tables, one by one by joining kindly refer to my answer below

Comment: @Aaron, not all DML stmts are single table operations. For example using OUTPUT clause in select stmt we can perform INSERT in 2 tables at the same time. For Delete yes unless Cascde is enable Delete is one table stmt in SQL server.

Comment: @Anup you can't use the OUTPUT clause to DELETE unless you output into another table which has a trigger that then performs a delete. In which case, why not just put a trigger on the table you're deleting. The target of the DML statement itself, whether you put any fancy dangling things after that, is still a single table.

Comment: I know we can not use OUTPUT clause for DELETE, and I was making a Note that when you say "No, a DML statement can affect only one table. " it is generic for all DML stmts and which is not true. Of course my comments is not helping the original question or OP but for other readers it might be misleading such generic stmt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nope, you'd need to run multiple statements.

Because you need to delete from two tables, consider creating a temp table of the matching ids:

```
SELECT U.Id INTO #RecordsToDelete
FROM Users U
   JOIN LinkingTable J ON U.Id = J.U_Id
...
```

And then delete from each of the tables:

```
DELETE FROM Users 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #RecordsToDelete)

DELETE FROM LinkingTable
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #RecordsToDelete)
```

Comment: I think the problem is a bi-directional foreign key, in which case separate statements won't work either (chicken + egg).

Comment: If that's the case, then perhaps dropping the constraint and adding it back after the delete runs could work as well.

Comment: I don't think EF - Code First allows you to disable / enable constraints on the fly, and it's probably not the optimal solution in a high concurrency environment anyway. If you're going to be turning off the constraint all the time, what's the point in ever turning it on?

Answer (score 4):

The way you say is Possible in `MY SQL` but *not* for `SQL SERVER`

You can use of the "deleted" pseudo table for deleting the values from Two Tables at a time like,

```
 begin transaction;

 declare @deletedIds table ( samcol1 varchar(25) );

 delete #temp1
 output deleted.samcol1 into @deletedIds
 from #temp1 t1
 join #temp2 t2
 on t2.samcol1 = t1.samcol1

 delete #temp2
 from #temp2 t2
 join @deletedIds d
 on d.samcol1 = t2.samcol1;

 commit transaction;
```

For brief Explanation you can take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

and to Know the Use of Deleted Table you can follow this [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you mean, "The way you say is Possible in MY SQL but *not* for SQL SERVER"?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think of is logically break the bi-directional foreign keys in a *procedural* way.

This approach can have huge impact to your application side if you don't have some flags for `visualization` state or `status`

Something like

1. `INSERT` dummy not visible rows to Users (with something like  `Id = -1` for dummy values)
2. Add to `LinkingTable` an alternative column to point back to `Users`, I'll call it `U_ComesFrom`

   ALTER TABLE LinkingTagble ADD U_ComesFrom_U_id INT DEFAULT(-1)
3. Add `FOREIGN KEY` with a `NOCHECK`

   ALTER TABLE LinkingTable WITH NOCHECK
   FOREIGN KEY (U_ComesFrom_U_id)
   REFERENCES Users (Id) ;
4. Add to `Users` column

   ALTER TABLE Users ADD MarkedForDeletion BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)

Then your SQL would look like

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE J
    SET U_Comes_From_U_id = U_ID, U_id = -1 -- or some N/R value that you define in Users
    FROM Users U
    inner join LinkingTable J on U.id = J.U_id
    inner join Groups G on J.G_id = G.id
    WHERE G.Name = 'Whatever'
    and U.Name not in ('Exclude list')

    UPDATE U
    SET MarkedForDeletion = 1
    FROM Users
    inner join LinkingTable J on U.id = J.U_ComesFrom_U_id 
    WHERE U_id > 0

    DELETE FROM LinkingTable 
    WHERE U_ComesFrom_U_id > 0

    DELETE FROM Users
    WHERE MarkedForDeletion = 1

COMMIT
```

This approach would impact the performance since each transaction would be at least 4 DML operations per bi-directional keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use TRY CATCH with Transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    DELETE from A WHERE id=1

    DELETE FROM b WHERE id=1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

or 
you can also use Store procedure for same
[Using Stored Procedure With Transaction:](http://queryingsql.blogspot.in/p/stored-procedures-in-sql-server.html?spref=bl)

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the foreign key through T-SQL you must append the ON DELETE CASCADE option to the foreign key:

```
Code Snippet 

ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraintname> FOREIGN KEY (<columnname(s)>)
REFERENCES <referencedtablename> (<columnname(s)>)

ON DELETE CASCADE;
```