# Unable to delete from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete all records of a person in a website that I created through an admin account. The query is as followed:

```sql
DELETE FROM users u, user_address ua, pending_order po, product_catalogue pc 
WHERE u.user_id = ua.user_id 
AND ua.user_id = po.user_id 
AND po.user_id = pc.user_id 
AND u.user_id = '$user_id'
```

`$user_id` is obtained from an `$_POST['user_id']` in a form.

I keep getting this error whenever I run it

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'u, user_address ua, pending_order po, product_catalogue pc WHERE
>   u.user_id = ua.' at line 1

What's wrong here?

Comment: You cannot delete from multiple tables in one statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539145/is-it-possible-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-the-same-sql-statement

Comment: Use multiple statements put them in a transaction.

Comment: Unless you've set up foreign keys with ON DELETE CASCADE, you can only delete from one table at a time

Answer (score 0):

You have to run one delete statement for each table:

```
delete from users where user_id = '$user_id';
delete from user_addresses where user_id = '$user_id';
delete from pending_order where user_id = '$user_id';
delete from product_catalogue where user_id = '$user_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

you must delete from tables one by one:

```
DELETE FROM users  WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM user_address WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM  pending_order WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM product_catalogue WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

If you are use large tables and MySQL Replication, this can be better sometimes (test it!):

```
$rows =  SELECT group_concat(id) FROM product_catalogue WHERE user id = ...
//$rows  = 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,155 or similar list)
DELETE FROM table WHERE id in ( $rows )
```

I am doing this sometimes when the list of deleted items is large and I want to minimize locks and replication lag.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) recommends... :)

```
DELETE FROM users u, user_address ua, pending_order po, product_catalogue pc 
using u inner join ua inner join po inner join pc
WHERE u.user_id = ua.user_id 
AND ua.user_id = po.user_id 
AND po.user_id = pc.user_id 
AND u.user_id = '$user_id';
```

Note: it might be less time-consuming to delete corresponding rows from four tables separately (if necessary, within one transaction). Especially if not in all of them user_id is an indexed field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete multiple tables with one statement delete statement..You need to do it seperately. It would be like

```
DELETE FROM users  WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM user_address WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM  pending_order WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM product_catalogue WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following as suggested above

```
DELETE FROM users  WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM user_address WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM  pending_order WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
DELETE FROM product_catalogue WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

a. But why don't you setup Foreign key relations, to achieve your desired result.

you have to create  user_id as the primary key in users table, and in the other tables 
user_address, pending_order, product_catalogue  declare them as foreign keys 
and accordingly modify your query by adding  ON DELETE CASCADE, this will delete all records with the associated with the passed $user_id in the child tables.

b. you can also setup MySQL Triggers, just google around for details on Triggers.

c. I have a different suggestion though.

Why don't you add a new column in your table called active_status and store the status of records as Active Inactive, so rather than deleting the record you just change the status of the records which you may refer to as a soft delete, use the same pk and fk concept in tables like on update cascade.