# sql delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I want to exec the following query:

```
DELETE 
   login,
   klantGegevens,
   orderGegevens
FROM login 
INNER JOIN klantGegevens ON login.klantid=klantGegevens.klantid 
INNER JOIN orderGegevens ON login.klantid=orderGegevens.loginNr 
WHERE login.klantId=3
```

I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Obviously there is something wrong between "DELETE" and "INNER JOIN".
(DELETE **login,klantGegevens,orderGegevens FROM login** INNER JOIN )

What should it be?

Thankyou.

EDIT :

[image]

I want to DELETE klantId 3.

Comment: Maybe this is some sql-server extension, but in normal SQL it doesn't make sense to delete individual columns.

Comment: `orderGegevensfrom` is missing something (specifically a space)

Comment: @Colonel Thirty I want to delete several rows from several tabels

Comment: You need to write three delete statements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delete from multiple tables in the same SQL statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539145/is-it-possible-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-the-same-sql-statement) and [How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if your attempt to use inner joins implies that you only want to delete a record if it exists in all 3 tables.

For this answer -- assuming you don't care (you just want to delete it wherever you find it):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.DeleteLotsOfStuff
(@id int)
AS

Begin

DELETE FROM login WHERE klantid = @id
DELETE FROM klantGegevens WHERE klantid = @id
DELETE FROM orderGegevens WHERE loginNr = @id

End
```

---

```
EXEC dbo.DeleteLotsOfStuff 3
```

---

Alternatively -- you can add constraints (primary key / foreign key relationship) to the main table, and then set it to `DELETE CASCADE'.  If you do that, then whenever you run (for example):

```
DELETE FROM login WHERE klantid = @id
```

It would automatically delete the corresponding rows from `klantGegevens` and `orderGegevens`.

More information on adding contraints here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax

```
DELETE L
FROM   login L
       INNER JOIN klantGegevens
               ON L.klantid = klantGegevens.klantid
       INNER JOIN orderGegevens
               ON L.klantid = orderGegevens.loginNr
WHERE  L.klantId = 3
```

Comment: thankyou for answering, but I already tried this and it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Sample data and Expected result would certainly help.

Comment: @Jenssen - It is not possible to delete more than one table in a single delete query. You have to write individual delete queries to delete each table

Comment: But I want to delete one row in multiple tables, not delete the tables! I want to delete the row where klantid=3   (loginnr in ordergegeven is klantid)

Comment: Deleting the table in the sense i meant deleting the row only. To delete a single row from three different tables you need to write three different delete queries.

Comment: oke thanks for clearing that up.