# ERROR: syntax error at or near "student_info" SQL state: 42601 Character: 8

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

```
DELETE student_info,admission_details,parent_info
FROM student_info LEFT JOIN admission_details
ON student_info.student_id = admission_details.student_id 
LEFT JOIN parent_info ON admission_details.student_id = parent_info.student_id 
WHERE student_info.student_id = 234
```

I am getting error in this code using Postgres 9.1. I used this query for the deleting the 3 tables data.

Comment: You cannot specify more than one table in the `DELETE` part

Comment: I think you actually want `DELETE ... USING`, but unfortunately you can only do that with a simple `WHERE` clause (i.e. using an inner join). You have to do a further outer join on `student_info`. Pretty sure there are examples in the manual under delete ... using.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete from more than one table at a time. You have to write individual delete statement for each table. You can use joins if you need.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server) may help you solve the problem. Here there is an accepted solution. It uses transaction for deleting from multiple tables.