# JPQL query delete not accept a declared JOIN?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql, sql-delete

I'm trying to understand why the Hibernate not accepts this follow JPQL:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Order order JOIN order.credit credit WHERE credit.id IN ?1")
void deleteWithListaIds(List<Long> ids);
```

The error that I receive is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
```

But accepts this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from Order order WHERE order.credit.id IN ?1")
void deleteWithListaIds(List<Long> ids);
```

The entity `Order` (the entity `Credit` does not map the `Order`s):

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_order_credit"))
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Credit credit;


}
```

In `select` statements, the two approaches are accepted, but I don't understand why Hibernate have this limitation or if I'm doing something wrong in my DELETE Jpql. I would like to declare the JOIN in the query.

The only way that I know to resolve this problem in more complex queries is create a subselect:

```
delete from Order order WHERE order.id IN (
    SELECT order.id FROM Order order
    JOIN order.credit credit
    WHERE credit.id in ?1)
```

Is this the right approach for more complex delete queries?

I'm using the Spring Jpa Repository in the code above and Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Comment: can you please post the relationship arguments (i.e. how are order in Credit and credit in Order) are defined

Comment: @osamayaccoub thanks, I edited the question with the relevant code.

Comment: also you can allow hibernate to log queries and check the generated queries ... I think the finally generated queries wont be the same ... also some databases have restrictions on deletion from multiple tables ... which db engine are u using  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server

Comment: MySQL won't let you delete when a subselect is involved on the same table, it will fail with `SQL Error: 1093, SQLState: HY000 You can't specify target table 'order' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand why Hibernate have this limitation.

It is specified as such in the [JPA Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) in section 4.10:

```
delete_statement ::= delete_clause [where_clause]
delete_clause ::= DELETE FROM entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]
```

So joins aren't allowed in delete statements.
Why this was decided this way is pure speculation on my side.
But the `select_clause` or `delete_clause` specify what the query operates on. While it is totally fine for a select statement to operate on a combination of multiple entities a join for a delete doesn't really make much sense.
It just forces you to specify which entity to delete.

> The only way that I know to resolve this problem in more complex queries is to create a subselect:
>
> Is this the right approach for more complex delete queries?

If you can't express it using simpler means then yes, this is the way to go.