# Sql - SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

Below is my query -

```
DELETE
FROM activity_details as ad, edit_details as ed
LEFT JOIN edit_details as ed
ON ed.details_id = ad.row_id
WHERE year(ad.activity_datetime)  = year(GETDATE())-10
```

I am getting error SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
  SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Can you please help me correct the syntax

Comment: For any new visitors, I suggest reading the comments under the answers; the question the OP is asking above is not their "true" question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Change it like following. You need to delete with `alias` name if you are using `FROM` in your delete statement.

```
DELETE ad
FROM activity_details as ad
LEFT JOIN edit_details as ed
ON ed.details_id = ad.row_id
WHERE year(ad.activity_datetime)  = year(GETDATE())-10
```

Comment: I need to delete row from ed also, where rowid of ad is activityid of ed

Comment: SQL Server allows only one table delete in one statement, you can't delete rows from multiple tables using a single statement, if you want to delete multiple, you can store the data in temp table and execute two seperate delete statements . If you want you can wrap those statements inside a transaction.

Comment: so how do we handle foreign key constraints.. because edit detaills has a foreign key which references rowid

Comment: If you want to do CASCADE DELETE, it should be defined in the FK, you can check more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Add alias name after `delete`

```
 DELETE ad
    FROM activity_details as ad
    LEFT JOIN edit_details as ed
    ON ed.details_id = ad.row_id
    WHERE year(ad.activity_datetime)  = year(GETDATE())-10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alias in the delete clause, and then have the `FROM`. I also suggest against `year(ad.activity_datetime)` and use a SARGable query:

```
DELETE ad
FROM activity_details ad
     LEFT JOIN edit_details ed ON ed.details_id = ad.row_id
WHERE ad.activity_datetime >= DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()-10),0)
  AND ad.activity_datetime < DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()-9),0);
```

Comment: I need to delete from ed also based on ed.details_id = ad.row_id

Comment: @shreya SQL Server doesn't affect multiple tables with a single DDL statement. YOu will need to issue 2 `DELETE` statements or implement cascading. But why were those details in your question?

Comment: so there is another table edit_details  whose foreign key is activity id and references rowid

Comment: @shreya that doesn't change my above comment. SQL Server still won't allow you affect multiple tables with a single `DELETE`.

Comment: so how do we handle foreign key deletion

Comment: You can implement cascading, or you'll need to run a `DELETE` on the other table first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove aliases from the your query.