# Delete from multiple tables with SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When I try to delete a whole row from 2 tables with my INNER JOIN I get the error shown at the bottom. I have searched on the internet and could not find the problem so I came here for help.

Here is the code:

```cs
    var delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE Posts, Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = @PostId;");
    delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
    _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(delete);
```

I am getting an error message:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'`

Comment: something like this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481475)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete from multiple tables using INNER JOIN in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem in the `SQL Statement`, it is not valid.

You should divide the statement into two ones:

First Delete `Comments`, then delete `Posts`

**Sequence is Important**

```
var deleteComments = new SqlCommand("DELETE Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = @PostId;");
        deleteComments.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
        _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(deleteComments);
        
var deletePosts = new SqlCommand("DELETE Posts WHERE PostId= @PostId;");
        deletePosts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
        _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(deletePosts);
```

**The other option, using one statement:**

```
var delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = @PostId; DELETE Posts WHERE PostId= @PostId;");
            delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
            _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(delete);
```

***More Explanation:***

Using the Following Prepared SQL Script using **SQL Studio** (SSMS):

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (PostId  INT, PostText varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE Comments (CommentId INT, PostId INT, CommentText varchar(20))

INSERT INTO Posts VALUES (1, 'text')
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES (1,1, 'comment here')
```

when I run your DELETE statement

```
DELETE Posts, Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = 1
```

It gives me the same error

When I run

```
DELETE Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = 1;

DELETE Posts WHERE PostId = 1;
```

It works fine.

**So the rule of thumb** in such cases is to use **SSMS (MS SQL Studio)** to test your SQL statement first **and then** implement it in C#.

Comment: this works but my stakeholder wants as less queries as possible. and in this it would make 2 separate connections to the database. Is there maybe a way I could fit it in one statement?

Comment: So just merge them

Comment: @U8080 you don't need INNER JOIN when you are deleting in this case because you already have PostId in that table. INNER JOIN will be additional overhead.

Comment: @JaapSmit The answer is in the comment just after your question.

Comment: Hi @Jaap Smit, the solution is updated with one statement as well

Comment: next time I will first try the sql statements on SSMS now i think about it its indeed a better way the handle these situations.

Comment: ```var delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE Comments FROM Posts INNER JOIN Comments ON Posts.PostId = Comments.PostId WHERE Posts.PostId = @PostId; DELETE Posts WHERE PostId= @PostId;");
            delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
            _dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(delete);```

Comment: @JaapSmit It doesn't really create a new connection. If you operate on the same SqlConnection object, that's still a single connection. And even if you're using multiple SqlConnection objects, there's still connection pooling. So don't worry about using too many connections for this: just write easy to understand and maintain code that performs well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in `MSSQL Server` to remove data from multiple tables in one statement. So, your statement `DELETE Posts, Comments FROM` is incorrect.

You have two options to set this foreign key to be `CASCADE DELETE` or to rewrite your statement for deleting data in these two tables like the following one:

```
var delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Comments WHERE PostId = @PostId; 
                             DELETE FROM Posts WHERE PostId = @PostId;");
delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostId", postId);
_dataAccess.ExecuteQuery(delete);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MS SQL query is incorrect. If you want to delete from mutiple tables, you have two choices:

1. setup cascading delete where a delete in one table  will automatically cause deletes in dependent tables
2. write separate delete queries such as:

- DELETE FROM Comments WHERE PostId = @PostId
- DELETE FROM Posts WHERE PostId = @PostId

However, I suggest that you test your queries through the SQL Management Studio first before trying to develop code for them.